# Java extending and overriding classes

Tags: java, overriding, extend

I've got two classes:

```
class A{
    method(){}
}
class B extends A{
    @Override
    method(){
        super.method();
        //some logic
    }
}
```

and I have created third one:

```
class C extends B{
       @Override
       method(){
       super.method();
       //more logic
    }
}
```

but I am not sure whether "some logic" will be executed. Could someone tell if it is or not and maybe recommend me good tutorial about extending classes and overriading methods?

Comment: Consider running it and testing it. Sprinkle in some println statements and you'll know your answer sooner than one can tell you here.

Comment: What makes you think that `// some logic` will _not_ be run, exactly?

Comment: If you make a `B` or `C` object, `//some logic` will be executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the super () class of an extending method the extended (parent) method will surrly be called.

Here's a good inheritance tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Both will of `//some logic` and `//more logic` will be executed if you call `method` on an instance of `C`. But you shouldn't take my word for it. To see what's happening try these things

- Add print statements to show you what bits of code are running
- Compile the program and disassmble it using `javap -c C` to see what code is being run. You will see calls to the super methods and then some code after it. When you run the method it will call this super method like any other method call and then return and continue as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily try it by placing some `System.out.println("some logic in B class");` and see that it is called.